# can't find tfm sometimes

Tags: fonts, paths

I'm trying to use [this Garamond package](http://gael-varoquaux.info/computers/garamond/index.html) to use its Garamond font, and I can't use it if I try to tidy the files into their own subdirectory.

Contrary to the instructions, if I unpack the zip in the same directory as my document (giving me a `package` directory with many .tfm and other files) and add `package` to my TEXINPUTS path, compiling fails with:

```
[1] (input/package/t1ggm.fd)
kpathsea: Running mktextfm ggmr8t
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ggmr8t
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf ggmr8t
! I can't find file `ggmr8t'.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ggmr8t

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ggmr8t

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: ggmr8t.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ggmr8t' failed to make ggmr8t.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font T1/ggm/m/n/7=ggmr8t at 7.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                  relax 
l.72 \garamond

?
```

However, if I extract all of the files from the `package` directory into the same directory as my document, it compiles fine and my text is in Garamond as desired.

I'd really prefer to keep all these files in a subdirectory, whether that's named `package` or (preferably) `garamond`. Is there some extra environment variable to set for the tfm files, so it doesn't try to compile them again from scratch?

Comment: what tex distribution are you using?  messing with texinputs is usually a *bad* *thing* in a modern tex system, and in any case it won't help with `tfm` and other font-related files.  in addition, i note that the garamond package you got "correctly" uses `ugm` for the font id, but all your error message refer to `ggm`.  have you hacked the package somehow?  if so, how?

Comment: I haven't hacked the package at all, just unzipped it and left the files in `packages` or moved them up one directory. I have no idea what's up with `ugm` vs `ggm`, I literally unzipped it, add `\usepackage{garamond}` and `\garamond` and it works or doesn't based on file location.

I'm using whatever distribution of TeX comes with Ubuntu 12.10, looks like TeX Live 2012.20120611-4. (If there's a command I can run for more useful info, please let me know).

As for TEXINPUTS, that's due to some hassle I posted another question about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a long command line for pdflatex anyways, so I stored the font files in a subdirectory named `garamond` and 'solved' it with a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FOO=`ls garamond`
cp garamond/* .

# pdflatex command here...

rm -f $FOO
```

I have no idea what model TeX is using for paths, but it doesn't match modern hypertext systems and I can't find any documentation of it, so it requires ridiculous workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

- The `garamond`(ggm) package is superseded by the [garamondx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/garamondx) package. Read the documentation of the latter to see what you gain when switching to the new package.
- In case `garamondx` is not already installed with TeXLive, and can not be installed via the package manager: TeX keeps its files in so called TEXMF trees, and expects a certain structure in them. One of the trees is the TEXMFHOME tree, usually located under `${HOME}/texmf` (This can be checked in the configuration file `texmf.cnf`, mine is located under `/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf`). Then you could manually download [this file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/fonts/garamondx.tds.zip) to `${HOME}/texmf` und `unzip` it there. Afterwards, running `texhash` will make all files of `garamondx` accessible to TeX. The `.tds.zip` files contain package files prestructured, suitable for a TEXMF tree.

But please try to get the package first via your package manager, or the TeXLive package manager.

Comment: This question was not really about Garamond, it was about how trying to load a local package is a confusing mess and I ended up with an ugly workaround. Garamond was only an example, and garamondx would have had the exact same problem because I had to tweak the font for my unusual work, so it also would have been in my project's directory rather than TeX's.

Comment: @pushcx This was just a reminder that there is a better garamond package, since you seem to use this ggm package. Regarding the local packages, I still think that those should go into a proper TEXMF tree. I mean, you don't tweak one and the same font in several different ways to have dozens of variants, don't you?